# Mule Convert payload string to CLOB for Oracle DB Insert

Tags: mule, mule-studio

The basic gist of the problem is how to take a string payload and convert it to CLOB for an oracle `<db:insert ... />`

I'll need to write and read CLOB data to and from an oracle database. The typical approach for converting String to CLOB is to do something like `db.getConnection().createClob()` and then set the data into this created CLOB. It doesn't appear that within MULE, this is a legitimate option as I won't (or at least non-trivially) have access to the connection object. (perhaps i can do some hacky stuff with creating a new connection and converting in a transformer?)

Looking back through documentation and prior versions, there appears to be an old property of `<jdbc:connector .../>` as of V3.5.x that could handle individual rows from the database and provide a custom handler for these rows. This jdbc connector has been deprecated and I expect it will be removed in future versions.

So how does this work? How does mule intend to do this? *How do i convert a String to CLOB for a* `<db:insert .../>`

Below is a sample flow that will reproduce ths problem.

[image: Simple Flow]

```
<db:oracle-config name="Oracle" host="localhost" port="1521" instance="testIns" user="myUser" password="myPass" doc:name="Oracle Configuration" />
<flow name="databaseInsertFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\test\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <!-- create table tblTest (cdata clob) -->
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into tblTest (cdata) values (#[payload])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
</flow>
```

**UPDATE:** 
Further review of the problem has shown that the issues lies with using the ojdbc7.jar driver. Reverting to ojdbc6.jar resolved the problem using the above flow.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution for insert that works* but is a terrible and ugly hack.

This solution is to ignore the mule-provided database connector and roll your own.

**below is the configuration needed:**

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="dbInserter" scope="prototype" class="kansas.InsertPayloadClob">
    <spring:property name="dbConnection">
        <spring:ref local="Oracle_Configuration"/>
    </spring:property>
  </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="databaseInsertFlow">
       <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:\test\input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
       <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
       <component doc:name="Java">
           <spring-object bean="dbInserter"/>
    </component>
   </flow>
```

**and a simple class to actually perform the database insert**

```
public class InsertPayloadClob implements Callable { 

private StaticDbConfigResolver dbConnection;

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    String src = eventContext.getMessageAsString();
    DbConfig config = dbConnection.resolve(null);
    try {
        DbConnection conn = config.getConnectionFactory().createConnection(TransactionalAction.JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE);
        Clob clob = conn.createClob();
        clob.setString(1, src);
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblClobTest (cdata) values(?)")) {
            stmt.setClob(1, clob);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
          }
        return 1; 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public void setDbConnection(StaticDbConfigResolver o){
    this.dbConnection = o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT SQL with CLOB

Inserting CLOB to database table can be done by the following configuration:

```
<db:insert config-ref="databaseConfiguration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
            <![CDATA[INSERT INTO T_IMPORT_FILE (CONTENT) VALUES (:content)]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="content" type="CLOB" value="#[payload]" />
</db:insert>
```